# Laravel Confirm order as Seller instead of Buyer. TokenMismatchException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I work on an little Laravel 5 Store where users can buy and sell stuff. After an Seller Delivered the Item , the Buyer can Confirm the Order and the Seller get the Money. (Only for learning Laravel and upgrade my skills)

Now i want coding an Button where also Sellers can Confirm the Order and get the Money instant self, not only Buyers.

The Buyer Code is in my `PurchaseController` all other Seller Tools in `ProfileController`.

I write the code in my `ProfileController` but i get this Error:

```
TokenMismatchException
```

seller.blade.php:

```
<form action="{{ route('confirm',['uid'=>$sale->uniqueid]) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

ProfileController:

```
public function ConfirmDelivery($uniqueid){
      $sales = Purchase::where('uniqueid',$uniqueid)->first();


      $sales->state = 2;
      $sales->save();
      $settings = Settings::first();
      $fee = (100 - $settings->fee)/100;
      if ($sales->product->auction == true) {
         $sales->seller->balance += $sales->value*$fee;
         $sales->seller->save();

         $settings->collected_fee += $sales->value - $sales->value*$fee;
         $settings->save();
      } else {
        $sales->seller->balance += $sales->value*$fee;
        $sales->seller->save();

        $settings->collected_fee += $sales->value - $sales->value*$fee;
        $settings->save();
      }
      return redirect()->route('oursales');
    }
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('confirm/{uniqueid}','ProfileController@ConfirmDelivery')->name('confirm');
```

Anyone an Idea how i can solve it?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `a href` link, you're sending `GET` request and your route is `POST`. You should use a form to send the data:

```
<form action="{{ route('confirm',['uid'=>$sale->uniqueid]) }}" ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="{{ route('confirm',['uid'=>$sale->uniqueid]) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<button type="submit" name="button" class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button>
</form>
```

You need a `{{ csrf_field() }}` if you want to create a POST request for security reasons.